# How to force gcc to use all SSE (or AVX) registers?

Tags: gcc, 64-bit, sse, register-allocation, avx

I'm trying to write some computationally intensive code for Windows x64 target, with SSE or the new AVX instructions, compiling in GCC 4.5.2 and 4.6.1, MinGW64 (TDM GCC build, and some custom build). My compiler options are `-O3 -mavx`. (`-m64` is implied)

In short, I want to perform some lengthy computation on 4 3D vectors of packed floats. That requires 4x3=12 xmm or ymm registers for storage, and 2 or 3 registers for temporary results. This should IMHO fit snugly in the 16 available SSE (or AVX) registers available for 64bit targets. However, GCC produces a very suboptimal code with register spilling, using only registers `xmm0-xmm10` and shuffling data from and onto the stack. My question is:

**Is there a way to convince GCC to use all the registers `xmm0-xmm15`?**

To fix ideas, consider the following SSE code (for illustration only):

```
void example(vect<__m128> q1, vect<__m128> q2, vect<__m128>& a1, vect<__m128>& a2) {
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        vect<__m128> v = q2 - q1;
        a1 += v;
//      a2 -= v;

        q2 *= _mm_set1_ps(2.);
    }
}
```

Here `vect<__m128>` is simply a `struct`  of 3 `__m128`, with natural addition and multiplication by scalar. When the line `a2 -= v` is commented out, i.e. we need only 3x3 registers for storage since we are ignoring `a2`, the produced code is indeed straightforward with no moves, everything is performed in registers `xmm0-xmm10`. When I remove the comment `a2 -= v`, the code is pretty awful with a lot of shuffling between registers and stack. Even though the compiler could just use registers `xmm11-xmm13` or something.

I actually haven't seen GCC use any of the registers `xmm11-xmm15` anywhere in all my code yet. What am I doing wrong? I understand that they are callee-saved registers, but this overhead is completely justified by simplifying the loop code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two points:

- First, You're making a lot of assumptions. Register spilling is pretty cheap on x86 CPUs (due to fast L1 caches and register shadowing and other tricks), and the 64-bit only registers are more costly to access (in terms of larger instructions), so it may just be that GCC's version is as fast, or faster, than the one you want.
- Second, GCC, like any compiler, does *the best register allocation it can*. There's no "please do *better* register allocation" option, because if there was, it'd always be enabled. The compiler isn't trying to spite you. (Register allocation is a NP-complete problem, as I recall, so the compiler will never be able to generate a perfect solution. The best it can do is to approximate)

So, if you want better register allocation, you basically have two options:

- write a better register allocator, and patch it into GCC, or
- bypass GCC and rewrite the function in assembly, so you can control exactly which registers are used when.

Comment: Actually, there is one other option I should have mentioned: fiddle with your code to make it more understandable to GCC and its register allocator. Declaring new variables instead of reusing old ones may help, minimizing the scope and lifetime of each variable as well, and just generally experimenting back and forth might help you coax GCC into producing different code

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. You are right that I was assuming to much. It turns out that the compiler produces the desired code if I store `a1` and `a2` in temporary local variables for the duration of the computation. For some reason, this wasn't an issue for the compiler when `a2 -= v` was commented out. Not sure why. About the instruction length, the new VEX encoding makes accessing all 16 registers equivalent.

Comment: Optimal register allocation (without spill/fill) is linear O(N) for SSA-form IR using either SEO or PEO. I can't remember what the current  best result is for allocation with spill/fill.

Comment: Well yeah, when I talk about register allocation, I mean the problem *as a whole*, not just the few special cases that are easy to handle.

Comment: @jalf More reading shows that the final spill phase is polynomial, although something like O(V^3). I'm not sure what you mean by 'few special cases', *all* programs are representable in SSA-form, and all SSA-form programs can be k-colored in linear timeusing SEO or PEO.

Comment: @thechao: I mean exactly what I said. In the general case, *optimal* (as in perfect) register allocation is a NP-complete problem. There are many cases where it is easier, but in general, it has been shown to be NP-complete. Which means that if you can do it in linear time, then you have solved a whole group of nasty problems that the brightest heads on the planet have failed to do. Which is pretty nice. (I haven't checked if the millenium prize is still going, but if so, hurry up and talk to them. They've got several several million dollars waiting for the guy who solves that problem. ;)

Comment: @jalf It sounds like you're not familiar with modern compiler design. Here's the following papers and presentations on O(N) optimal register allocation for the general case:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15745-s07/www/papers/presentations/register_allocation.pdf

http://www.docstoc.com/docs/11350331/Register-Allocation-via-Coloring-of-Chordal-Graphs

I understand that graph coloring can be reduced to register allocation, when RA is posed as a general graph problem. However, programs aren't general graphs and, as such, are optimally colorable in O(N). This is a fairly new result.

Comment: @thechao That's not the takeaway from that research. You can transform any program into SSA, and do optimal register allocation on SSA in linear time, but that doesn't mean you did optimal register allocation for your original program. SSA introduces more variables in order to simplify the graph structure. With that simpler structure you can optimally allocate registers, but it's only optimal for that simpler structure with the greater number of variables; the end result is not an optimal allocation for the original problem. Read the presentations that you linked to; they say just that!

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @thechao you're right, I wasn't aware of those papers. Thanks for bringing them to my attention. Very interesting stuff. But as Brian says, there are still a few caveats. Nevertheless, I stand corrected. :)

Answer (score 6):

Actually, what you see aren't spills, it is gcc operating on a1 and a2 in memory because it can't know if they are aliased. If you declare the last two parameters as `vect<__m128>& __restrict__` GCC can and will register allocate a1 and a2.